# Is there a way to clear readline prompt line?

Tags: node.js, command-line

I've been looking around everywhere and I was still unable to find an answer.

I have an example program here which requests input with `readline` and then logs something after the input was entered.
Here is an extremely basic example:

```js
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

rl.question("What is your name? ", function(res) {
    console.log("Hey, your name is", res);

    rl.close();
});
```

What I want to do is completely hide `What is your name? (name)` after `enter` was pressed and only show `Hey, your name is ...`. It seems like such a basic thing but after hours of research I failed to find a solution.

I have tried `process.stdout.clearLine()` but since `enter` makes a new line, it clears that new line instead which keeps the input. I have also tried appending `\r` to the end of the input but since `enter` creates a new line, the same happens as with `clearLine`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using the [`readline.moveCursor`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_movecursor_stream_dx_dy_callback) and [`readline.clearScreenDown`](https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_readline_clearscreendown_stream_callback) methods.

```js
const readline = require("readline");
const rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);

console.log("Hello there (dont delete this)");
rl.question("What is your name? ", function(res) {
  // moves up 3 lines (question + answer + enter new line)
  readline.moveCursor(process.stdout,0,-3);
  readline.clearScreenDown(process.stdout);
  console.log("Hey, your name is", res);
  rl.close();
});
```

[Example REPL](https://repl.it/@theusaf/ModernScentedOolanguage#index.js)

You may need to perform some math if the question or response contains new lines.

Comment: I want to only get rid of `what is your name? ...`, not anything before that.

Comment: I have updated my answer to fit the criteria